# Product quantity incremet/decrement on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, quantity

I have a product collection on home page and there I have put increment and decrement buttons.Buttons are working fine, The problem I am currently facing is the updated new quantity is not showing on cart page.

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($a); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $a->getId() ?>"<?php if ($a->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                                                    <div class="qty-box">
                                                        <?php if (!$a->isGrouped()): ?>
<!--                                                            <label for="qty"><?php // echo $this->__('Qty')   ?></label>-->
                                                            <a class="minus" id="<?php echo $a->getId() . "minus" ?>" href="javascript:void(0);">-</a>
                                                            <input type="text" name="qty" class="input-text clone-qty" id="qty<?php echo $a->getId() ?>"disabled="true" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($a->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty() ? $a->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty() : 1) ?>" /> 
                                                            <a class="plus" id="<?php echo $a->getId() . "plus" ?>"  href="javascript:void(0);">+</a>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn-cart button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add') ?></span></button>
                                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($a); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $a->getId() ?>"<?php if ($a->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                                            <div class="qty-box">
                                                <?php if (!$a->isGrouped()): ?>
                                                    <a class="minus" id="<?php echo $a->getId() . "minus" ?>" href="javascript:void(0);">-</a>
                                                    <input type="text" readonly="true" name="qty" id="qty<?php echo $a->getId() ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($a->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty() ? $a->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty() : 1) ?>" />
                                                    <a class="plus" id="<?php echo $a->getId() . "plus" ?>"  href="javascript:void(0);">+</a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn-cart button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add') ?></span></button>
                                        </form>






 $j(document).ready(function() {
                                                    $j(".minus").click(function() {
                                                        var id = this.id;

                                                        var value = $j('#' + id).next('input').val();
                                                        var fieldID = $j(this).next('input').attr("id");


                                                        if (value > 1) {
                                                            value = value - 1;
                                                            $j('#' + fieldID).val(value);
                                                        }


                                                    });
                                                    $j(".plus").click(function() {
                                                        var id = this.id;

                                                        var value = $j('#' + id).prev('input').val();
                                                        var fieldID = $j(this).prev('input').attr("id");


                                                        ++value;

                                                        $j('#' + fieldID).val(value);


                                                    });
                                                });
```